# Why isn't there a Team Foundation Server Express Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

Why isn't there a Team Foundation Server Express Edition?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Almost 3 years and 16 answers later,[**TFS Express**](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs) is now a fact.

Comment: Your link now redirect somewhere else, [this seems to be the new url](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs)... But you'll need to scroll a bit.

Comment: Actually this is the new [link to TFS Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio)

Answer (score 13):

The Express Editions are specifically designed for individuals who do not have access or, more bluntly, cannot afford the full versions of Visual Studio but who would like to develop in the .NET Framework.

Team Foundation Server on the other hand, is specifically designed for *corporations* which has software development teams with a number of members. Corporations (nor startups) have never been the target of the Express product.

You can still take advantage of Express editions and collaborative tools by using open source products in conjunction with them, e.g., use Subversion for source control, Cruise Control for continuous integration, etc. They will give you most of what you need and still allow you to use the Express editions in a team environment.

I am not sure, however, if specifically using Express editions in a team environment is a violation of its EULA. Hope not :P

Comment: You can use the Express editions in a Team/Corporate environment, and you are able to sell the software you write using the Express editions without limitation.

Answer (score 10):

There is an Express version of TFS coming out with Visual Studio 2012:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Because Microsoft is [positioning TFS](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/vsts_pricing.html) to compete with software like [ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearcase),  releasing a free edition would undermine that positioning.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the source-control a bug-tracking functionality that TFS provides, there are a number of free products out there that can do it for you like CVS or Subversion if you want something open source. TFS is meant to be used by very large teams, addressing the kinds of problems you have with very large teams - using it for just source control is total overkill.

I prefer Sourcegear's products (they're free for single developers) - [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/index.html) if you're just looking for source control, and [Vault Professional](http://www.sourcegear.com/vaultpro/index.html) (previously called "Fortress") if you want source control along with bug and work item tracking, which covers most of TFS's functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's an interesting question, but the real question is what the usage scenario for such a thing would be?

In particular, I see TFS as focusing heavily on supporting dev *teams*. (Whether it does a good job of that or not, it's a different matter). Certainly individual developers could benefit from things like the source control facilities in TFS, but it's not clear how a single individual would take advantage of a lot of the functionality in TFS.

And, for pure source control, there are already good alternatives for that already on the market (the way I see it)

Also, it's interesting to note that TFS has some substantial hardware, software and environment requirements that I'm not sure would make it easy for a single individual to host; unless he can spare one machine just to run it (some people do it; I find it a waste of a good machine, myself :)).

And for small teams, there's already TFS WorkGroup Edition, which I guess is as close as MS is going to get to TFS express.

Answer (score 1):

And individuals shouldn't be using TFS?? That's like saying source control is only for groups and not individuals.

If they had an express edition of TFS, then they'd probably get more people using it and paying for their company to use it.

Comment: There is a trial version of TFS, I imagine that was their aim for that rather than giving away a slightly cut down version.

Comment: No, it's just saying that "Team" foundation server is for teams and not individuals writing code by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could say that there is an Express version! [Codeplex](http://codeplex.com)! Just like the express editions of Visual Studio have certain limitations, you can use Codeplex for free, but you must develop open source.

Comment: True, I'll give you that one. But, and a BIG BUT, is you can only use CodePlex for Open Source Software development. Good point though.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the TFS workgroup edition somewhat fill this 'express' role?  5 users or less and the price is very 'express' when compared to the full 800 pound gorilla.

Answer (score 1):

IBM have a similar product to TFS, Rational Team Concert, and its available for free for a small number of users.

Answer (score 1):

At last Express edition of Team Foundation Server is also available. Check it out [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express).

Answer (score 0):

No, from memory anything Team Foundation based costs a few times more than the professional versions.  That's where Microsoft really makes its money.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't make much money off of it's programming tools.  If it were any other market, it would be far too small for Microsoft to bother with it.  The only reason they make programming tools at all is to get people to program for their OS.

Comment: FYI, MS now makes a billion dollars a year off its programming tools. Times have changed.

Comment: A billion dollars a year is less than 2% of Microsoft's revenues.

Comment: I've never met a corporate accountant who would want to wipe out 2% bottom line by giving stuff away.  Anyway, it's more profit than other areas of the company as the production of development tools must have a rather large in-house target audience.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward answer is that TFS doesn't scale DOWN well enough for it to be worthwhile. TFS is very much aimed at development teams of medium, large, and huge sizes, it's not designed well for very small teams.

Also, on the small scale there are already pretty high quality free, or inexpensive, source control systems available, so it doesn't make much sense for MS to put effort into competing in that area.

I would suggest using SVN with the [VisualSVN plug-in](http://www.visualsvn.com/) if you require source control, which everyone does, on the cheap.

Look at it this way, Visual Studio 2008 Standard is a $250 product.  How much of that functionality exists in, say, Visual C# 2008 Express? At least the equivalent of $25 worth? Most likely. At least $10 easily. VSTS 2008 Team Foundation Server is a $2500 product. If they did the same amount of feature reduction to make a TFS Express edition it would be worth $250, which is a bit much to give away for free. More so, a lot of the value of TFS is in its scalability and core feature-set, which is almost impossible to strip away to create a simplified, cheaper product.

Comment: Unless I miss my guess you can't use VisualSVN with the express editions because MS doesn't allow the express editions to be extended.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that Microsoft doesn't have a SQL Server Express version of TFS is because TFS includes SSAS under the covers. I doubt there will ever be an "express" version of SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download the TFS Express Edition Beta: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#tfs-express